# Through model that changes depending on the model it is "throughing" to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
User has_many vehicles, through: :workable
```

`Workable` has a couple of generic fields, and a couple of fields that depend on the `Vehicle` it links to.

Given that I have about 8 vehicles, should I be content to stick all of the vehicle-unique fields into workable? or should I look at a different structure for my database?

Comment: Vehicle is like a vehicle-type? And workable is the actual vehicle of a certain type?

Comment: Vehicle is the actual vehicle. It has information about that vehicle. Workable says that a user is willing to work using that vehicle.

Comment: Ok. Can you give an example of a vehicle related attribute in workable?

Comment: a boolean that asks whether the user has a delivery box on their motorbike. Wouldn't apply to a car!

Comment: You say: "the user has a deliverybox", is this because the box belongs to the user, and every time he switches vehicle he takes the box with him, or is that because the user is the sole driver of the bike? (but actually the box is specific to the vehicle).

Answer (score 0):

I would put `Vehicle` specific fields in the vehicles table and then use [delegate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) to simplify the use of the vehicle data within `Workable`

Comment: Cheers! But the `Vehicle` table is a static one that doesn't know about the user, it's just a list of vehicles with some accessors about the vehicle. Each row is a vehicle, not a user owning a vehicle.